# how can I save docker's database data locally on my server?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm running an app inside a docker container. That app uses docker Postgres image to save data in a database. I need to keep a local copy of this database's data to avoid losing data if the container is removed or purged somehow ..so I am using `volumes` inside my `docker-compose.YAML file,, but still the local DB folder is always empty .. so whenever I move the container or purge it the data are lost

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "2"

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    restart: always       
    command: -p 5433
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydata
      - POSTGRES_USER=mydata
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydata@
      - PGDATA=/tmp


  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: rolla_django
    restart: always 
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydata
      - POSTGRES_USER=mydata
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mydata@
      - PGDATA=/tmp
    ports:
      - '4002:80'
      - '4003:443'
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html
      - ./www/demo_app/static_files:/var/www/html/demo_app/static_files
      - ./www/demo_app/media:/var/www/html/demo_app/media

#    command: sh -c 'python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata db_backkup.json && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'
    command: sh -c 'wait-for-it db:5433 -- python manage.py migrate && apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND'

    depends_on:
      - db
```

as you can see i used `./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data` , but locally the `./data/db` directory is always empty !!

**NOTE**

when I use `docker volume list` it shows no volumes at all

Comment: I’m not sure what the environment variable `PGDATA` does, but it seems to be a path, and could be the cause of your data not being where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your setup, the data is in `/tmp`: `PGDATA=/tmp`. Remove this and you volume mapping should work.

Also your command `-p 5433` makes postgres run on port 5433, but you still map the port 5432. So if you cant reach the database it might be because of that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even after removing the lines with `PGDATA=/tmp` the local folder still empty , also about the port mapping yes am using different one because i have more than 1 container on the same server

Comment: by the way, when I use docker volume list it shows no volumes at all

Comment: the command refers to the port inside the container and in there you only have 1 database. think about it

Comment: I doublechecked and the host folder contains data. You can also add another volume like: `-./data2:/tmp` and see what you get in there. Also `docker volume` will not return you anything because this is not a docker managed volume, it is a host folder. You see it with `ls`